# Focus only elements on Tab keypress with "tabindex" property defined

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, web, vuejs3

I am developing a web application using Vue.js. I have a data entry form with 5 fields.
The business need is on tab keypress, it should focus the first Input box and on subsequent tabs the next next element should be focused. I have archived using tabindex property to the elements.

Now the issue that I'm facing is after the form elements are over and when we hit tab it goes to the other elements where tabindex is not defined such as  links and Browsers' URL bar.

What I want is if I have 6 elements (5 textbox + 1 submit button) and I have set tabindex from 1 to 6 than again after tab at element with tabindex 6 it should again focus on tabindex 1 and ignore other links and buttons on webpage.

Comment: You can create a variable `let tabPressedCount = 0` and then increment `1` after each tab press and then as soon as tabPressCount reach `6` then reset the `count` to 0 and then repeat the same.

Comment: Which version of vuejs? If vue3, Composition or Options API?

Comment: @Bravo Yup it's vue3 with composition API.

Comment: are the input fields `<input>` etc or some component?

Comment: @Bravo no it is large form with multi type elements and it have TomSelect component for select option.

Comment: @newCode Did you checked the solution which I provided ? He just took the reference from my answer and modified. I think you should accept the original idea answer. Btw it's up to you. No complaints :)

Comment: @RohìtJíndal - your solution won't help - wrong version of vue, options API, and will fail the same way

Comment: @newCode - I added the vuejs3 tag to your question, as stated in the `vue.js` tag, you should add one of `vue2js` or `vue3js` tags as well when using `vue.js` tag - since the two versions are so different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI - This is @RohitJindal's **Vue 2** answer using **Vue 3 Composition API**

Modified so shift-tab on the first element moves to the last

Note: you'll need to renumber your tabindexes if you want to do it like this

```js
const { createApp, onMounted } = Vue;
createApp({
    setup() {
        const focusFirst = () => {
            document.querySelector('[tabindex="2"]').focus();
        }
        const focusLast = () => {
            document.querySelector('[tabindex="6"]').focus();
        }
        onMounted(focusFirst);
        return { focusFirst, focusLast};
    }
}).mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.37/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <span tabindex="1" @focus="focusLast"></span>
  <input type="text" tabindex="2"/><br>
  <input type="text" tabindex="3"/><br>
  <input type="text" tabindex="4"/><br>
  <input type="text" tabindex="5"/><br>
  <button id="button" tabindex="6">Submit</button>
  <span tabindex="7" @focus="focusFirst"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It works fine with the native HTML elements but it's not working fine when there is TomSelect select control added to the form. I guess it's issue with the TomSelect Library.

Comment: @newCode Did you checked the solution which I provided ? He just took the reference from my answer and modified. I think you should accept the original idea answer. Btw it's up to you. No complaints :)

Comment: @RohìtJíndal - your solution will equally fail with "TomSelect" - since this solution is based on your solution (with improvements AND using the correct vue version and API)

Comment: @newCode - what is TomSelect - a link would be nice

Comment: @RohìtJíndal yes, I tried your solution also, that's also giving the same issue.

Comment: @Bravo https://tom-select.js.org/plugins/dropdown-input/ this one with the search option

Comment: please add **to your question** exactly how you are using it - because that may impact how the code works @newCode

Comment: @Bravo i will update a part of my code and update the question in a while cuz it's large form and other things will be non relevant.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent the focus outside `tabIndex` by place an empty span at the end of the last index element. Give it an `id` with `tabindex = 0` along with an `onfocus` event, On trigger it help to focus to the first `tabindex` element.

```
<span tabindex="0" id="prevent-outside-focus" onfocus="foucsFirstTabIndex()"></span>
```

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mounted() {
    document.getElementById('field1').focus();
  },
  methods: {
    foucsFirstTabIndex() {
        document.getElementById("field1").focus();
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" id="field1" tabindex="1"/><br>
  <input type="text" id="field2" tabindex="2"/><br>
  <input type="text" id="field3" tabindex="3"/><br>
  <input type="text" id="field4" tabindex="4"/><br>
  <button id="button" tabindex="5">Submit</button>
  <span tabindex="0" id="prevent-outside-focus" @focus="foucsFirstTabIndex()"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: nice - does this work in vue3?

Comment: @Bravo I can see there is `vue.js` tag attached in the OP and this will work in Vue 3 as well.

Comment: OP mentioned in comments before you posted this answer, that they are using vue3 composition API - so while this code probably works in vue3, it may not - have you tried in vue3

Answer (score 0):

You can focus elements without the use of `tabindex`.

Vue.js allows to select DOM elements with this kind of syntax `this.$refs.name`
(and if it doesn't work you can try `this.$el.querySelector('yourElementSelector')`

After selecting the element you can add `focus()` to it.
For instance `this.$refs.name.focus()`;

At your specific case, you can add `this.$refs.name.focus()` after an `onclick` event on the tab.

That will focus the element right after the click

Comment: does this equally apply to vue2, vue3 (options API) and vue3 (composition API)?